# Limit set of tent map

Tags: dynamical-systems

Consider the tent map $f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$, 
$$f(x) = 2 x \; \text{if} \; 0 < x < \frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$f(x) = 2(1 - x) \; \text{if} \; \frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 1.$$
What does it mean $\textbf{the limit set of}$ $f$?

Thank you!

Comment: The expression "limit set" has no meaning in this context. Probably you mean $\omega$-limit set (but not of $f$, instead of a point).

Comment: The context is the dynamic behaviour of iterates of $f$.

Comment: A good reference then (for $\omega$-limit sets): http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/C.Good/research/pdfs/barwell-etal.pdf. Otherwise you need to be more detailed.

Comment: Since $f$ is surjective its $\omega$-limit set is $[0,1]$. However, this is not much informing about dynamics. The dynamical behavior of this map is illustrated in some detail in the book of R. Devaney: "Introduction to chaotic dynamical systems" if I remember correctly.

Comment: In general, the limit-set of a map is the set of all its limits for different initial values of that map. It looks like the limit-set of this one is for $x=0.5$ i.e. $\{1\}$